# How to get the java process command on linux if the command is too long?

Tags: java, linux, command

There is a java process which includes too many jars in classpath, so the startup command is very long.

So as view the process command using command 'ps', don't view completely, it is interrupted.

It's only show about 4000 characters.

Is there a method to see the entire command?

`ps aux > /tmp/aa`

View the command in the file /tmp/aa, then will find that the command was interrupted because it is too long.

It's not the problem that can be resolved by:

`ps aux | grep java`

or

`ps -auxww`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only one java process, then you can use `cat /proc/$(ps ax | grep java | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')/cmdline`. Of course, you can tweak the `grep java` as needed.

Comment: The bad news is that the file `/proc/{processId}/cmdline` is incomplete too. My command was `cat /proct/57375/cmdline`

Comment: What about `ps eww -p $processId`?

Comment: It doesn't work too. Only show about 4118 characters. Because the command is very very long.